# Output video from Ubuntu Thinkpad to Epson EMP-821 projector

Tags: ubuntu, video, thinkpad, projector

I have Ubuntu running on a Thinkpad Helix. I bought a used Epson EMP-821 overhead projector and found a cable to connect the computer to it.

The cable is USB on the computer side and some sort of square video output on the other (apparently I bought this years ago and I don't remember what you call it).

The projector powers on and which I press "Source Search" it finds the computer (it says `Source: Computer2 (Auto)`.

However, I can't determine how to send video to the projector. If this were Windows I believe `Fn-7` would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu. I also tried Displays -> Detect Displays.

Answer (score 2):

The USB cable (A to Standard-B) is just to allow the computer to control the projector via software. It does not carry video. You'll need an actual video cable to output video to the projector.

The only video output on the ThinkPad Helix, as far as I can tell, is Mini DisplayPort. To connect to your projector, you'll need to get a [Mini DisplayPort (mDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) to [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) adapter and a VGA cable. Connect the adapter to the mDP connector on the computer and the cable to the adapter and either of the two inputs on the projector marked "Computer/Component Video".

Comment: Thanks. I actually think I have one of those. I'll give it a try tonight and report back.

Comment: @Hack-R: Did you get it to work?